# How can I add multiple existing forms in a VB6 project?

Tags: vb6

How can I add multiple existing forms in a VB6 project?

I have about 200 forms, and copying each form is getting weird for me...

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to add multiple existing forms (or any other file) to your VB 6 project. Simply follow these steps:

1. Right-click on your project in the "Project Explorer" window.
2. In the context menu that appears, point to "Add", and click "Add File".
3. In the dialog that appears, navigate to the folder that contains whatever forms you want to add.
4. Single-click to select the form that you want to add. If you want to add multiple forms, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while making your selections.
5. Click the "Open" button. All of the forms that you selected will be added to your project.

Comment: Holding down the CTRL key doesn't allow me to select multiple files. How did you do this?

Comment: It doesn't work to select multiple files, and I get an error saying the element already exists, but it's not there in the project explorer.